# Counting struct elements in 2D vector C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have a 2D vector of structures of this type

```
typedef struct box
{   
    int boxVal;
    char boxTakenBy;
} box;
```

I have `myvector` defined as:

```
vector<vector<box> > myvector(10,vector<box>(10))
```

My goal is to count number of elements with `boxTakenBy == 'X'`. I tried:

```
int mycount =  std::count_if( myvector.begin(), myvector.end(),
[](const box &p ) { return p.boxTakenBy == 'X'; });
```

I am getting compilation error :

```
no match for call to ‘<lambda(const box&)>) (std::vector<box >&)
```

Not sure if my approach is wrong or just the syntax. Please correct if you find any syntax issue or suggest if any better approach is out there.

Comment: Various solutions are possible. Easiest: add a loop iterating over outer vector elements which are vector themselves, and call the `std::count_if` on those. That's what you missed: the *myvector* elements are not of type `box`, but actually: `vector<box>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by [hauron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/754407/hauron) elements of `myvector` are not `box`es but `vector<box>`s. So what you need to do it iterate over 2 dimensions of `myvector`.

You can combine [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) (to accumulate the sum) and [`std::count_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) (to count the inner elements satisfying your condition ( `== 'X'`) to achieve that like so:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

struct box
{   
    int boxVal;
    char boxTakenBy;
};

int main(){
  using namespace std;
  vector<vector<box> > myvector(10, vector<box>(10));

  myvector[0][0].boxTakenBy = 'X';
  myvector[2][0].boxTakenBy = 'X';
  myvector[2][7].boxTakenBy = 'X';
  myvector[5][7].boxTakenBy = 's';

  int total_count = std::accumulate(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), 0,
                                    [](int acc, const vector<box>& curr)
                                    {
                                      return acc + std::count_if(curr.begin(), curr.end(),
                                        [](const box& b ) { return b.boxTakenBy == 'X'; });
                                    }
                                   );

  std::cout << total_count << '\n';
}
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af623bc2faba60a1)

Answer (score 3):

You have two levels of vectors, so you need to traverse both.

You can use `count_if` to count the elements in each "inner" vector, then sum the results with `accumulate`:

```
int count = std::accumulate(myvector.begin(),
                            myvector.end(),
                            0,
                            [](int i, const vector<box>& bs)
                            { return i + std::count_if(bs.begin(),
                                                       bs.end(),
                                                       [](const box& b) 
                                                       { return b.boxTakenBy == 'X';}); });
```

or, pulling out the innermost function and abstracting out the character:

```
auto takenBy = [](char c) { return [=](const box& b) { return b.boxTakenBy == c; };};
int count = std::accumulate(myvector.begin(),
                            myvector.end(),
                            0,
                            [&](int i, const vector<box>& bs)
                            { return i + std::count_if(bs.begin(),
                                                       bs.end(),
                                                       takenBy('X')); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution can be to use `std::for_each` and `std::count_if` as following:

```
int mycount;
std::for_each( myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), 
 [&mycount](std::vector<box> const &p ) 
  { mycount += std::count_if(p.begin(),p.end(),[](box const & q){return q.boxTakenBy == 'X'; });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard library algorithms are great and everything but sometimes I think a ranged-based for loop is simpler:

```
auto mycount = 0;
for(const auto& row : myvector)
  for(auto& item: row)
    if (item.boxTakenBy == 'X') ++mycount;
```

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/znwqL693lKIr8CzG).